# Имена файлов с исходным кодом в C/C++

Tags: c++, c, header

1. Имеются ли какие-нибудь ограничения для имени source-файла в C/C++? (в Java, например, имя source-файла должно совпадать с именем класса в нем)
2. Должны ли .h/.hpp и .c/.cpp файлы иметь одинаковое имя? Если нет то когда я пишу #include как компилятор узнает где находится реализация header'а?

Comment: 1. нет. 2. нет. Когда вы пишете инклюд, то компилятор просматривает все инклюд пути + папку проекта. Файлы с реализацией компилируются все, которые включены в проект (msvc) или то, что скормлено компилятору (g++)

Comment: @goldstar_labs спасибо, но я не совсем понял каким образом компилятор находит реализацию хедера

Comment: Возможно я не понимаю вопрос, что значит находит? Компилятор компилирует все файлы с исходным кодом, создавая промежуточные объектные файлы, из которых потом компоновщик делает исполняемый файл (причем компоновщик работает как с объектными файлами, так и со статичными библиотеками, поскольку их реализация также должна быть включена в исполняемый файл)

Comment: Компилятор даже не пытается искать файл с реализацией того, что объявлено в заголовочном файле. Программист должен сам явно скомпилировать и слинковать соответствующую единицу трансляции, иначе вылезут ошибки `Undefined reference...`

Comment: Компилятор ищет включаемые файлы по неким стандартным путям (например, `/usr/include`; `/usr/local/include`; `/usr/include/<triplet>`; компилятор C++, кроме того, заглядывает в `/usr/inlude/c++/<version>`), а также по тем дополнительным путям, которые ему указаны тем или иным способом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете называть, как хотите - даже необязательно с расширением .cpp или подобным, только тогда надо пояснить компилятору, что это - исходный текст, а не что-то иное :)

Заголовочные файлы вообще могут быть какими угодно - так как их имя четко указывается в директиве `#include`.

То, что вы называете "реализацией хедера", обычно находится в библиотеках, которые подключаются компоновщиком. Или, если это ваш код - в одном из ваших .cpp-файлов, например. Или в нескольких :) - как уж вы напишете. Или даже в собранной вами собственной библиотеке.

Comment: Ну не совсем как хотите, например если обозвать header именем `foo>".h` подключить его уже не получится =)